# Razor @Html.DropDownList() do not take the selected value from List<SelectListItem> selected value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my controller a have this:

```
List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Text = row["ProgramName"].ToString().Trim(),
                        Value = row["Id"].ToString().Trim(),
                        Selected = row["selected"].ToBoolean()

                    });
```

but when I send the object to the razor view I get it like this

```
@Html.DropDownList("ListaProgramas", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["ListaProgramas"], new {@class = "form-control pull-left", @id = "ListaProgramas", @style = "color:black; width:100%;" })
```

That look like this:

[image: DropDownList showing...]

but Razor not set selected value. What i would do for resolve this issue ?

The HTML is this

```
<select class="form-control pull-left" id="ListaProgramas" name="ListaProgramas" style="color:black; width:100%;">
<option selected="selected" value="1">VIADR</option>
<option value="2">TweakedBPclient</option>
</select>
```

But in my controller I selected a different one

```
List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Text = row["ProgramName"].ToString().Trim(),
                        Value = row["Id"].ToString().Trim(),
                        Selected = valor

                    });
```

I want HTML Razor view take as selected the element that I selected in the controller code.

Comment: What does the generated HTML actually look like?

Comment: This look like this. HTML put selected the first one, do not carer what I selected.                                                                                                       
 <select class="form-control pull-left" id="ListaProgramas" name="ListaProgramas" style="color:black; width:100%;"><option selected="selected" value="1">VIADR</option>
<option value="2">TweakedBPclient</option>
</select>

Comment: Edit your question and add it there :)

Comment: Do you have a model declaration in the view? If so, you should probably be using the strongly-typed helpers, and definitely _not_ ViewData.

Comment: No, I do not have. I just use ViewData for do this, I do not want create a model for this simple function, but if I have, I will.

Comment: Setting the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` is ignored wen binding to a model property. Its the value of `ListaProgramas` that determines what s selected. Set the value of `ListaProgramas` to a value that matches one of your options values and that option will be selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When crafting your `SelectList`, use this form instead:

```
new SelectList(ViewData["ListaProgramas"], "Value" , "Text", itemToSelect);
```

Where `itemToSelect` is the appropriate `row["Id"]` - since you don't have a model in play, you can pass this value in via the ViewData, as well. That being said, I also advise using strongly-typed views and helpers and simply setting the value in the model that is passed to the view, thereby cutting out the need to specify the `itemToSelect` parameter altogether.

Comment: Thank you so much Sleeyuen. I will use a model for do this or send the selected value in a ViewBag variable.